# OAuth Token from extension response keys are genrrtaing 401 error

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app, shopware6-api

I have refered the follwoing link for development.

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-base-guide

I have received api key and api secret  from extension installation response but i am aunable to generate the the access token using them, but if i create an acces key manually that key is generating the O Auth is there some step i am missing or settings i might have changed , because this use to work before.
But now i am getting the following error.

[OAuth Genration Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrJ4m.png)

Received Client Id and Client Secret using Extension install response.

But these using these credentials i am not able to generate the OAuth token.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `integration` table of the Shopware installation. It should have an entry with the `access_key` you received and `label` being the technical name of your app. The column `secret_access_key` contains the encrypted secret.

First make sure that this database record even exists. Then verify that the `access_key` value equals the one you received.

If all is correct up to that point, test the validity of the secret you received by checking it against the encrypted password stored in the database:

```php
var_dump(password_verify($secretReceived, $encryptedSecretFromDatabase));
// should be "bool(true)"
```

When you use those credentials for the token request, [make sure to use `"client_credentials"` for the `grant_type` property](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/8e1d78252fa6f-authentication#obtain-an-access-token).

Comment: the keys that i am receiving from rthe reponse do exists int he databse and shopware GUI but still it shows the 401 error i sendding the request in the below format

```{
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "client_id": "***********************",
  "client_secret": "***********************"
}```